# Kivy and matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, kivy

I just wanted to know if matplotlib is compatible with kivy 1.9.0, and how I do I go about implementing it if it's possible? If it's isn't supported, does kivy have something very similar to it?

I want to able use this particular code from one my programs in my kivy app:

```
def printPieChart(table, column):
    if column == 6:
        columnList = table.iloc[:, -1:].values.T.ravel()
    else:
        columnList = table.iloc[:, (column - 7): (column - 6)].values.T.ravel()
    countedList = Counter(columnList)

    #set up the size of the pie chart
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cmap = plt.cm.prism

    #input variables for pie function
    slices = [float(v) for v in countedList.values()]
    colors = cmap(np.linspace(0., 1., len(slices)))
    labels = [float(k) for k in countedList]
    columnHeaders = list(table.columns.values)

    #the pie chart
    pie_wedge_collection = ax.pie(slices, colors = colors, labels = labels, labeldistance = 1.05, autopct = '%1.1f%%')
    #get rid of the black outlines between the wedges and around the pie
    for pie_wedge in pie_wedge_collection[0]:
        pie_wedge.set_edgecolor('white')
    ax.set_title(columnHeaders[column + 1])
```

If I wanted to make a compilation recipe for matplotlib would it be along these lines?

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION_matplotlib=${VERSION_matplotlib:-1.4.3}
DEPS_matplotlib=(numpy python dateutil pyparsing six linpng pytz freetype agg PyCXX qhull ttconv)
URL_matplotlib=http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-$VERSION_matplotlib.tar.gz
MD5_matplotlib=f43c20480a1673185afefc7d4848a1d2
BUILD_matplotlib=$BUILD_PATH/matplotlib/$(get_directory $URL_matplotlib)
RECIPE_matplotlib=$RECIPES_PATH/matplotlib

# function called for preparing source code if needed
# (you can apply patch etc here.)
function prebuild_matplotlib() {
    true
}

function shouldbuild_lxml() {
    if [ -d "$SITEPACKAGES_PATH/matplotlib" ]; then
        DO_BUILD=0
    fi
}

# function called to build the source code
function build_matplotlib() {
    cd $BUILD_matplotlib

    push_arm

    export CC="$CC -I$BUILD_numpy/"
    export LDFLAGS="-L$BUILD_numpy/numpy/.libs -L$BUILD_numpy/numpy/.libs -L$BUILD_numpy/.libs -L$BUILD_numpy/numpy -L$BUILD_numpy/numpy -L$BUILD_numpy/  $LDFLAGS"
    export LDSHARED="$LIBLINK"

    chmod +x $BUILD_numpy/numpy-config
    export PATH=$PATH:$BUILD_numpy
    #plus more for the other dependencies
    try $HOSTPYTHON setup.py build_ext -I$BUILD_matplotlib
    try find . -iname '*.pyx' -exec $CYTHON {} \;
    try $HOSTPYTHON setup.py build_ext -v
    try find build/lib.* -name "*.o" -exec $STRIP {} \;

    export PYTHONPATH=$BUILD_hostpython/Lib/site-packages
    try $BUILD_hostpython/hostpython setup.py install -O2 --root=$BUILD_PATH/python-install --install-lib=lib/python2.7/site-packages

    unset LDSHARED
    pop_arm
}

# function called after all the compile have been done
function postbuild_matplotlib() {
    true
}
```

Comment: There is a `garden.graph` project (https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph), but it doesn't have a pie chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call matplotlib from a kivy script fine, exactly as you normally would, but kivy has no built in way to display plots - you'd have to get matplotlib to render them (e.g. as png, or you could try kivy's experimental svg support but it might be buggy) then display them in an Image widget or similar.

If you want to do this on android or ios, you'd need a compilation recipe for matplotlib, as I don't think we have one yet. I think that shouldn't be too hard and we'd be happy to discuss if if you're interested.

We do have a GSoC student working on giving us proper matplotlib support, so there may be good news on it in the next few months.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. While I am interested but I'm not too sure that I'd be able to follow along as well as I'd like to since I'm fairly new to programming in general let alone python and kivy.

Comment: The reason I asked this question was because I wanted to see if I can make an android  app out of a program I made for my Computer Science AS degree final project. I'll try out kivy's svg to see if that works for what I had in mind.

Comment: @inclement any news on the matplotlib support? it would be very nice.