# Resizing the buttons in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

```
import numpy as np
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class myLayout(BoxLayout):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super(myLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

         btn1 = Button(text = "click 1", background_color=[0,0,1,0],pos=(200, 100))
         btn1.bind(on_press=self.clk1)
         btn2 = Button(text = "click 2", pos=(200, 100))
         btn2.bind(on_press=self.clk)
         btn3 = Button(text = "click 3", pos=(50, 100))
         btn3.bind(on_press=self.clk)

         self.add_widget(btn1)
         self.add_widget(btn2)
         self.add_widget(btn3)

    def clk(self, obj):
         print("Hello WOrld")

    def clk1(self, obj):
         dataset = np.genfromtxt(fname='data.txt',skip_header=1)
         print dataset

class NameApp(App):
     def build(self):
     mL = myLayout()
     return mL

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NameApp().run()
```

This program is running fine however i am not able to figure out why the size and position of buttons are not changing?

dataset contains numeric value say say two dimension

1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

how can i plot these values inside the GUI?

Comment: Here you are using `boxlayout` which will ignore `pos`, Try some other layout like  `floatlayout` or `relativelayout` or any other and then use `pos, size_hint or pos_hint.` See here http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html

Comment: Hi kiok46, Thanks for the suggestion it works with FloatLayout. However i am wondering how can i plot in the layout screen.

Comment: Ook I will post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with `Float Layout`

add this in your main.py file

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
...
btn1 = Button(text = "click 1",pos=(200, 200),size_hint = (.1,.1))
btn2 = Button(text = "click 2", pos=(200, 100),size_hint = (.1,.1))
btn3 = Button(text = "click 3", pos=(50, 100),size_hint = (.1,.1))
```

OR

```
btn1 = Button(text = "click 1",pos_hint= {'x': .1,'top': .2},size_hint = (.1,.1))
btn2 = Button(text = "click 2", pos_hint= {'x': .4,'top': .2},size_hint = (.1,.1))
btn3 = Button(text = "click 3", pos_hint= {'x': .66,'top': .2},size_hint = (.1,.1))
```

See [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.html) under layout section for more on layouts.

You might wanna checkout [KivyCatalog](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/demo/kivycatalog) and [KivyShowcase](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/demo/showcase).

**EDIT: 1**

Oops! I forgot to add this part.

> how can i plot these values inside the GUI?

Use `Label`

```
self.lbl = Label(pos_hint= {'x': .73,'top': .6},size_hint = (.1,.1))
self.add_widget(self.lbl)

def clk1(self, obj):
....
self.lbl.text = str(dataset)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. However there are quite few points i want to ask. Using label i can only see the result, but not plot it (visualization). Can u tell if it is possible to visualize if so then how can i do it?. Can someone use python libraries such as pyplot for 2D or 3D plots?

Comment: And also see inclement's answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157687/kivy-and-matplotlib

Comment: Hi, yea i saw some examples with garden and seems OK to me. I have directory garden inside kivy folder however when i run command garden install graph it shows error as it is not able to locate C:\Users\stiwari\kivy however my path to kivy is: C:\Users\stiwari\kivy downloads\kivy-1.9.0\    any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
import math
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import os

class myLayout(FloatLayout):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(myLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       btn1 = Button(text = "click 1",pos_hint= {'x': .1,'top': .2},size_hint = (.1,.1))
       btn2 = Button(text = "click 2", pos_hint= {'x': .4,'top': .2},size_hint = (.1,.1))
       btn3 = Button(text = "click 3", pos_hint= {'x': .66,'top': .2},size_hint = (.1,.1))

       btn1.bind(on_press=self.clk1)
       btn2.bind(on_press=self.clk2)
       btn3.bind(on_press=self.clk3)

       self.add_widget(btn1)
       self.add_widget(btn2)
       self.add_widget(btn3)

   def clk1(self, obj):
       print("Hello World")

   def clk2(self, object):
       Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
       filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
       print(filename)

   def clk3(self, object):
       graph = Graph(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', x_ticks_minor=5,x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True, padding=5,
     x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=-0, xmax=100, ymin=-1, ymax=1)
       plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
       plot.points = [(x, math.sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]
       graph.add_plot(plot)
       self.add_widget(graph)

class NameApp(App):
   def build(self):
       mL = myLayout()
       return mL

if __name__ == '__main__':
   NameApp().run()
```

Here is the running code, however how can i use canvas to draw plots and option to change size and shape of it.